# Flask: Jinja for loop works only once per template

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I have a Flask app and I am using a for loop to generate html dynamically:

```
    {% for subcategory in subcategories|unique: %}
List of projects:
        <p> {{ subcategory }}</p>
        {% endfor %}


    {% for subcategory in subcategories|unique: %}
List of subcategories:
       <p> {{ subcategory }}</p>
        {% endfor %}
```

However, the second for loop does not produce anything.

If I delete the "|unique" then it works.

Why?

Comment: is the data coming from database?

Comment: it does not matter, I get the same result if the data comes from database and if its hard-coded by me

Comment: What you have posted works properly with a hardcoded list; I tried it myself. Any issue you are having is likely a results of some other part of your code.

Comment: If it is coming from database, it will be like a generator. Once you run the loop, then you can't able to access the data again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be passing in a generator as opposed to a list or other iterable object.

An example generator might be:

`subcategories = [str(item) for item in subcategories]`

On the Python end, try wrapping the item in a list before sending it over to the Jinja renderer:

`subcategories = list([str(item) for item in subcategories])`